# Set of maximum overlaps

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, combinatorics, sets

Assume I have a list of $N$ surfaces $\{S_i\}, i \in [1,N]$ which may or may not overlap.

I also have a boolean function $F(S_{i_1},\dots,S_{i_k})$ (with $1 \le k \le N$) which tests whether *all* surfaces $S_{i_k}$ overlap (or if they were discrete sets, then $F$ would test whether they contain a common element). In other terms: $F(\{S_{i_k}\})=\;\; (\;\cap_{j=1}^{k} S_{i_j} \;\;!=\;\;\emptyset \;)$.

I now consider the "set of maximum overlaps", $L_\rm{max}=\{O_1,\dots,O_m\}$, where each $O_j$ is a set with $n(j)$ elements being surfaces that all share a common intersection. More specifically: $O_j=\{S_{j_1},...S_{j_{n(j)}}\}$ with $\cap_{i=1}^{n(j)} S_{j_i} \ne \emptyset$ (or equivalently $F(O_j)=\rm{True}$).

$L_\rm{max}$ is unique once defined through the following two constraints that it must satisfy:

a) Each surface must appear in *at least* one overlapping set $O_i$ of $L_\rm{max}$.

b) Each overlapping set $O_i$ in $L_\rm{max}$ must be "maximal" in the sense that there cannot exist a surface $S_j$ *not* part of $O_i$ and for which its intersection with the intersection of all surfaces in $O_i$ is not empty.

One may write this definition of $L_\rm{max}$ more formally as follows:

$L_\rm{max} := \; \{ O_j \}\;\rm{with}\; O_j=\{S_{j_1}\dots S_{j_{n(j)}} \} \;|\;$

$\;\;\; \forall j \; \cap_{i=1}^{n(j)} S_{j_i} \ne \emptyset \;,$

$\;\;\; \forall i \; \exists\; j\; \rm{s.t.}\; S_i \in O_j\;,$

$\;\;\; \forall j \; \not\exists\; r\; \rm{s.t}\; (\; S_r \notin O_j \; \rm{and}\;S_r \cap (\cap_{i=1}^{n(j)} S_{j_i}) \ne \emptyset\;) $

Now, the problem is to identify the algorithm building $L_\rm{max}$ and requiring the *least expected number of calls* to the function $F$, assuming that any legal solution set $L$ is equally likely before the problem is investigated by successive calls to the function $F$.

The above sounds complicated but it is visually very simple to illustrate. I therefore include below a graphical representation of the problem for 5 surfaces (but please answer the abstract problem, not the particular realisation below):
[image: Example problem]

In that example, the solution set $L_\rm{max}$ is:

$\{ \{S_1, S_2, S_3\},\; \{S_3, S_4\},\; \{S_5\} \}$

And here are some examples of the output of the function $F$:

$F(S_1, S_2)=\rm{True}$

$F(S_3, S_4)=\rm{True}$

$F(S_3, S_5)=\rm{False}$

$F(S_1, S_2, S_3)=\rm{True}$

$F(S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4)=\rm{False}$

$F(S_2, S_4)=\rm{False}$

$F(S_i)=\rm{True}, \forall i$

etc...

Note that I am curious as to what is the exact answer to this set-theoretic puzzle with no reference to the particularity of the example above (e.g. the surface $S_i$ could very well be discrete sets too).
My hope is that someone may recognise this problem to be isomorphic to some other known mathematical problem with an established solution.

In practice however, my academic research would actually benefit from a solution tailored to the case of *convex* volumes (but with parametric equations of higher degree than quadratic and in an arbitrary number of dimension). 
In particular, I would be very interested if someone knows how to cast the derivation of the set $L_\rm{max}$ into a *single* convex-constrained optimisation problem.

Also, an algorithm proven optimal is of course not required, rather just an algorithm featuring a less disastrous complexity than the one of the naive implementation I came up with so far (which saturates around N=10 and I would need around N=100).
Maybe this problem really is NP hard after all, but the question remains as to what is the algorithm of minimal expected complexity...

Comment: If I understood you right, then there can be multiple smallest solution, for example for sets $\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{3, 4\}, \{4, 1\}$ size of the smallest solution is equal to 2 and you can split it in more then one way.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, my definition of the set of maximum overlaps is not the one I intended. I edited my question and corrected the definition of $L_\rm{maxl$ so that it is now indeed unique and the problem is well-posed.

Comment: Unfortunately there could be as many as $N \choose {N/2}$ sets in $L_{\max}$: That's the maximum size of a Sperner family (a family of sets in which no set contains any other: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806691/big-oh-for-size-of-a-sperner-family) for more).  That means the output size is exponential in $N$, and I don't see a way to invoke your boolean test function fewer than $O(\text{output size})$ times.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to Sperner family. This seems indeed like a concept very closely related to my problem.
It now seems clear to me that this problem is indeed NP hard. However, it remains unclear to me what is the optimal sequence of calls to the test function $F$.
Indeed, when calling $F(S_{i_1},\dots,S_{i_k})$ with a large $k$ (i.e. testing for the common intersection of *many* surfaces) one potentially gains a lot more information at once than with $k=2$ if the test is positive, which is however less likely.

Comment: So clearly there must be an optimal way of building $L_{\rm max}$ with successive calls to $F$ with various number of arguments $k$ which optimally balances this trade-off between the amount of information gained by the intersection test and the likelyhood that it is positive as a function of the number of arguments $k$.

An extreme illustration of this trade-off is that if *all* surfaces overlap, then you can solved the problem with a single call to $F$ with all surfaces in argument obviously.
However, this test is always useless *except in that complete overlap case*.

Comment: I am therefore looking for an algorithm where I could tune some hyper-parameter controlling how "optimistic" one is when deciding the number of surfaces to check for simultaneously with a single call of $F$.
In particular, for the case of an equiprobable distribution of all possible legal solutions $L_\rm{max}$, I am wondering what this choice may be.

Comment: My intuition is different: The most informative possible test is one that gives "yes" 50% of the time in expectation, and I think high-$k$ tests will give "yes" a very low proportion of the time, unless the distribution of answers is heavily skewed towards answers with a few large sets.  I suspect that for "reasonable" distributions, initial tests with $k=2$ are optimal.

Comment: I think the equiprobable solution distribution is very unfriendly here, because there are many near-worst-case solutions that will take a lot of work whatever we do, and relatively few "nice" solutions that we could hope to solve quickly.  Take for example the $n \choose {n/2}$ Sperner bound solution: You can produce $n \choose {n/2}$ different nearly-as-bad solutions by starting from this and deleting a single set.  While OTOH as you observed there is only 1 "complete overlap" case that can be solved with one function call, and only $n$ "complete overlap except 1" cases, etc.

Comment: Before making any calls to the test function, every possible answer could be the right answer; every time we call the function and get its response, this shrinks the set of possible correct answers; when this set has shrunk to size 1, we know the answer and can stop.  A particular algorithm can be completely represented by a binary tree where each node is labelled with 2 things: the set of possible correct answers at that point, and the next test function query; one child represents the set of answers that we infer contains the correct answer if the test function returned "yes", ...

Comment: ... the other child the same if it returned "no".  At the root is "all answers"; each leaf is a single-answer set.  Your goal is to find a tree that minimises the sum of all weighted root-to-leaf paths, where the weight of a path is the probability of the answer at its leaf (for equiprobable solutions, you can use 1 for all weights).  Of course it's completely infeasible to calculate this with brute force for any reasonable $N$, but this is the right way to think about the problem I think.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Indeed, this binary tree representation sounds promising. In practice, we have some prior information about some of the surfaces that we know already intersect. Also, we know that our distribution of solutions $L_\rm{max}$ is actually skewed towards containing "maximum overlapping sets" of large cardinality. It therefore seems that the binary tree representation of the search may be quite suitable for feeding in such information.
I may try to build the tree explicitly then for small N to see if I can derive some guiding principle for implementing our search.